# Cómo actualizar tabla en un div con editor de secuencia de comandos (GAS)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, div

Estoy trabajando en un código que lea varios registros de un spreadsheet y los muestre en una tabla html para que el usuario pueda editarlos.

La tabla esta anidada en un div:

```
<div id="lookTable">
     <table id="tableAdmin">
      <tr>
       <th style="width:170px">Dirección</th>
       <th style="width:50px"># Sacas</th>
       <th style="width:90px">Teléfono</th>
       <th style="width:80px">Conductor</th>
       <th style="width:70px">Estado</th>
       <th style="width:80px">Recogido por</th>
       <th style="width:80px">Recepción</th>
       <th>Observaciones</th>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
```

y al cargar la pagina muestro los registros dinámicamente:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(checkAdmin).getDataRecogidas();

  function checkAdmin(data){
   var tabla = document.getElementById("tableAdmin");
   for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][9] == who){
     var row = tabla.insertRow(1);
     var toInsert = 0;
     for (j=0; j<12; j++) {
      if(j==1){
       var cell = row.insertCell(toInsert);
       radio = document.createElement("input");
       radio.type = "radio";
       radio.name = "rRadios";
       radio.value = data[i][0];
       radio.setAttribute("onclick", "clickThis()"); 
       cell.appendChild(radio);
       var label = document.createElement("label");
       label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i][j]));
       cell.appendChild(label);
       toInsert ++;
      }
      if((j==5)||(j==6)||(j==7)||(j==8)||(j==9)||(j==10)||(j==11)){
       var cell = row.insertCell(toInsert);
       cell.innerHTML = data[i][j];
       toInsert ++;
      }
      if (j==5){cell.style.textAlign="center";}
      if (j==6){cell.style.textAlign="right";}
      if (j==10){cell.style.textAlign="center";}
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

Necesito que al editar los datos y guardar se actualicen los datos de la tabla html y e intentado usando la recomendación que encontré en  https://codepen.io/ashikjs/pen/yJpwkO para actualizar el Div

```
$("#lookTable").load(" #lookTable > *");
```

pero no me muestra la tabla de nuevo, hay alguna otra forma de actualizarlo???

Comment: La recomendación que citas usa jQuery pero tu código HTML no está completo por lo que no podemos saber si estás cargando o no esa librería.

Comment: Si estoy usando jQuery ...

Answer (score 0):

Para actualizar el HTML cuando se modifica una hoja de cálculo debes refrescar la hoja de cálculo o bien incluir algo que llame de nuevo

```
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(checkAdmin).getDataRecogidas();
```

Por ejemplo, podrías poner un temporizador que esté consultando la fecha de última edición de la hoja de cálculo y si esa fecha es más reciente que la última vez que se efectuó la actualización ejecutarla.

Comment: En la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30634581/1595451) de Mogsdad a [How do I make a Sidebar display values from cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30628894/1595451) se incluye un ejemplo de temporizador. La función se llama poll.

Comment: Esa opción me carga las filas pero no borra las que ya tenia, encontre la forma de "navegar" por la tabla y cambiar los datos no desde el spreadsheet sino desde el formulario mas adelante lo subo por si tiene alguna utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

Esta "solucion" muestra los cambios realizados en un formulario asociado a una tabla:
[image: Formulario asociado a un tabla]

Para cargar la data en la tabla:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(checkAdmin).getDataRecogidas();

  function checkAdmin(data){
   var tabla = document.getElementById("tableAdmin");
   for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][9] == who){
     var row = tabla.insertRow(1);
     var toInsert = 0;
     for (j=0; j<12; j++) {
      if(j==1){
       var cell = row.insertCell(toInsert);
       radio = document.createElement("input");
       radio.type = "radio";
       radio.name = "rRadios";
       radio.value = data[i][0];
       radio.setAttribute("onclick", "clickThis()"); 
       cell.appendChild(radio);
       var label = document.createElement("label");
       label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i][j]));
       label.id = data[i][0]+"-"+toInsert+"-"+toInsert;
       cell.appendChild(label);
       var cellId = data[i][0]+"-"+toInsert;
       cell.id=cellId;
       toInsert ++;
       //console.log(cell.id);
      }
      if((j==5)||(j==6)||(j==7)||(j==8)||(j==9)||(j==10)||(j==11)){
       var cell = row.insertCell(toInsert);
       cell.innerHTML = data[i][j];
       var cellId = data[i][0]+"-"+toInsert;
       cell.id= cellId;
       toInsert ++;
       //console.log(cell.id);
      }
      if (j==5){cell.style.textAlign="center";}
      if (j==6){cell.style.textAlign="right";}
      if (j==7){cell.style= "padding:0px 0px 0px 10px";}
      if (j==8){cell.style= "padding:0px 0px 0px 10px";}
      if (j==9){cell.style= "padding:0px 0px 0px 10px";}
      if (j==10){cell.style.textAlign="center";}      
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

Al seleccionar el Radio se muestra el registro en el formulario

```
var wRadios;

  function clickThis(){
   var tRadios = document.getElementsByName('rRadios');
   for (i=0; i<tRadios.length; i++){
    if(tRadios[i].checked){
     wRadios = tRadios[i].value;
     //console.log(wRadios);
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(openRecogida).getDataRecogidas();
    }
   }
  }

  var wPoblac, wNumcon;

  function openRecogida(data){
   $("#formChange").show().css('display', 'flex');
   for (i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    //console.log(data[i]);
    if (data[i][0] == wRadios){
     document.getElementById("id").value=data[i][0];
     //console.log(document.getElementById("id").value);
     document.getElementById("direcc").value=data[i][1];
     document.getElementById("nrosac").value=data[i][5];
     document.getElementById("numtel").value=data[i][6];
     document.getElementById("fecrec").value=data[i][10];
     document.getElementById("obsrec").value=data[i][11];
     wPoblac= data[i][2];
     wNumcon= data[i][7];
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildPoblac).getListPoblac();
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildNumcon).getListCond();
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildAvirec).getListAvirec();
    }
   }
  }
```

Luego de actualizar los datos se actualiza la tabla:

```
function updateHTML(data){
   var tRadios = document.getElementsByName('rRadios');
   for (i=0; i<tRadios.length; i++){
    if(tRadios[i].checked){
     wRadios = tRadios[i].value;
     console.log("Radio checked: "+wRadios);
     var i = 0;
     var encontrado = "false";
     while (i < data.length && encontrado=="false") {
      console.log("Mientras")
      console.log(data[i][0]==wRadios);
      if (data[i][0]==wRadios){
       console.log("if data es igual a wRadio");
       var cell = document.getElementById(wRadios+"-"+0);
       document.getElementById(wRadios+"-"+0+"-"+0).innerHTML=document.getElementById("direcc").value;
       document.getElementById(wRadios+"-"+1).innerHTML=document.getElementById("nrosac").value;
       document.getElementById(wRadios+"-"+2).innerHTML=document.getElementById("numtel").value;
       document.getElementById(wRadios+"-"+3).innerHTML=document.getElementById("numcon").value;
       document.getElementById(wRadios+"-"+6).innerHTML=document.getElementById("fecrec").value;
       document.getElementById(wRadios+"-"+7).innerHTML=document.getElementById("obsrec").value;
       encontrado= "true";
      }
      i++;
     }
    }
   }
  }
```